# SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql9.5

> SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unq_phones_new_phone_idcampaing_month_uindex"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (phone, idcampaing, month)=(79234695538, bpc, 2019-10-01) already exists. (SQL: update "unq_phones" set "phone" = 79234695538, "operator" = not found information, "region" = not found information where "idt" = 1853113)

Обновляю запись в бд и выходит ошибка. БД postgresql

Comment: А в чем проблема? Всё же написано. У тебя есть *уникальный* индекс `unq_phones_new_phone_idcampaing_month_uindex`, и в указанном уникальном индексе уже есть запись с указанными данными.

Comment: И что делать ? Запись то в базе одна и нужно просто ее обновить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть уникальный ключ `Key (phone, idcampaing, month)`, состоящий из 3 полей: телефон, id кампании и месяц. На то он и уникальный, что повторяться не может. Это значит, если у вас уже есть такая комбинация в базе данных, то вы не можете ни **вставить** новую запись с таким же набором данных, ни **изменить** любую другую на такую.

Comment: Спасибо! Но погуглив лучше уже понял это. Но все равно спасибо за толковое объяснение!